# Simple limit with Lambert W function

Tags: limits, special-functions

Basically, I just want to show that the right derivative of $W(-xe^{-x})$ at $x=1$ is $1$:

[WolframAlpha: plot lambertW(-x*e^(-x)) for x=0 to 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20lambertW(-x*e%5E(-x))%20for%20x%3D0%20to%202)

[image: Plot]

Equivalently, I want to prove the following limit:

$$
\lim_{x\to 1^+} \frac{W\left(-xe^{-x}\right)+1}{x-1} = 1
$$

[WolframAlpha: limit x->1+ of (lambertW(-x*exp(-x))+1)/(x-1)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+x-%3E1%2B+of+(lambertW(-x*exp(-x))%2B1)%2F(x-1))

L'Hôpital doesn't help, because it goes back to the same limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearer if you plot the second real branch too (I set $x = -x$):

[image]

If $y = W_k(x e^x)$, then $F(x, y) = y e^y - x e^x = 0$. The second-order terms in the Taylor expansion of $F$ around $(-1, -1)$ are $C (y + 1)^2 - C (x + 1)^2$, therefore the tangents to the curve $F = 0$ are $y = x$ and $y = -x -2$.