# Limit of derivative of implicit function

Tags: limits, implicit-function

Define $f(x)=x(1-x)^s$, where $x\leq 1$ and $s>0$. Note that this is an inverted-U-shaped function with peak at $x=1/(1+s)$. Given $x$ not equal to $1/(1+s)$, define $y(x)$ implicitly by (i) $f(y)=f(x)$ and (ii) $y\neq x$. That is, $y(x)$ is the other value of the argument at which $f$ attains value $f(x)$. I would like to compute the limit of $y'(x)=f'(x)/f'(y(x))$ as $x$ goes to $1/(1+s)$ from below. I’ve experimented around numerically and I’m pretty sure this limit equals $-1$, but I can’t prove it.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3175787). We want to show that the curve $y (1 - y)^s - x (1 - x)^s = 0$ has two tangents with slopes $\pm 1$ at the singular point $(1/(s + 1), 1/(s + 1))$.

Comment: Let F(x,y)=y(1-y)^s-x(1-x)^s and let f(x,y) be the second-order expansion of F around (1/(1+s),1/(1+s)). It's easy to see that f(x,y)=0 and y!=x implicitly defines y(x)=2/(1+s)-x, which has derivative -1. But does that allow me to conclude that y(x) implicitly defined by F(x,y)=0 and y!=x is differentiable at x=1/(1+s) and has derivative -1 at that point? If yes, based on which theorem?

Comment: If you need a rigorous proof, it might be simpler to start with parametrizing $y = y(x)$ as
$$(x, y) =
\left( \frac {t^{1/s} - 1} {t^{1/s + 1} - 1},
 \frac {t (t^{1/s} - 1)} {t^{1/s + 1} - 1} \right)$$
(with $x(1) = y(1) = 1/(s + 1)$).

Comment: I don't think this parameterisation works. With it, y(1-y)^s=x(1-x)^s does not hold for t different from 1.

Comment: Make sure that you're using the correct order of operations when evaluating $1/s + 1$.

Comment: My order of operations was fine, but I'd messed up elsewhere. Sorry, my mistake. I was able to find the limit using your parameterization. Very neat. Thank you, @Maxim.